# What do you take "put out" to mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

What do you take "put out" to mean in the following context?

> We had no sooner arrived at the address than I had other things to think of.
> “Mr. Dickson? He's gone,” said the landlady.
> Where had he gone?
> “I'm sure I can't tell you,” she answered. “He was quite a stranger to me.”
> “Did he express his baggage, ma'am?” asked Pinkerton.
> “Hadn't any,” was the reply. “He came last night and left again to-day with a satchel.”
> “When did he leave?” I inquired.
> “It was about noon,” replied the landlady. “Someone rang up the telephone, and asked for him; and I reckon he got some news, for he left right away, although his rooms were taken by the week. He seemed considerable **put out**: I reckon it was a death.”

(From The Wrecker by R. L. Stevenson and L. Osbourne, chapter X, published 1892) https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_10

Comment: put out = ***annoyed***

Comment: and/or "inconvenienced, and showing it in his tone of voice".

Comment: And 'considerable' is dialect for 'considerably'

Comment: Also can be a transitive verb, e.g. my sister put my father out by finishing off his bottle of whisky.

Comment: @Michael Harvey - Does that mean 'your' sister guzzled the whisky by herself completely???

Comment: Jack Sprat could eat no fat,
his wife could eat no lean,
but between the two of them,
they wiped the platters clean.

Comment: My  father's bottle had a small amount of whisky left and my sister drank that.

Comment: To put someone out can mean to inconvenience them, e.g. _would it put you out if I parked my car in your driveway?_

Comment: In my childhood, Mrs & Mrs Sprat had only one platter, and they **licked** it clean.

Comment: That sounds much better actually :)). (Typo: the first Mrs. or the last Mrs. -> Mr.)

Comment: Put out=upset/inconvenienced

Comment: Did you check any dictionary before asking? One of the expectations we have of people asking questions is that they do a minimal search themselves, like in a dictionary, before asking. If you did that search and didn't find an answer, please include in your answer what you found and why it was unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the context, the following definitions of [put out](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/putout) all could fit:

> - to confuse; embarrass:
>   *It put her out badly when she went to pay and realized her wallet was still at home.*
> - to vex or annoy:
>   *He was put out when I missed our appointment.*
> - to subject to inconvenience:
>   *I don't want to put you out, so I'll wait until after dinner to stop by.*

Since the landlady tells Loudon she reckons Mr. Dickson was informed about a death, it seems most fitting the latter was **vexed** (annoyed or troubled) by the call.